# Fortran sorting/ordering

Tags: fortran

I am looking for fortran routines that perform ranking. That is given a one dimensional array I would like a routine that returns the indices in that array of the (descending) sorted values. All I could fined are routines that perform sorting. Additionally it would be nice to have a routine that performs partial ordering. That is returning for a given number M the indices of the M biggest values - and others in any order. I found dlasrt but it only does sorting...

Comment: If you have the source code of a sorting routine, allocate a second array that contains the indices 1,2,3,... and everytime you move values, move the indices with them. For the M biggest, make an array of M value/index pairs, and maintain that (in sorted order) while you're going through the array. That's a lot simpler than sorting.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like however to avoid writing a subroutine myself as it could be error prone. Also its hard to optimize it for large arrays. Do you know about any implementation?

Comment: Sorry, no don't know of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for partial-sorting you just can just choose a sorting algorithm like selection sort and terminate after the first required number of elements rather than all of them. Make sure that you (partial-)sort a parallel array of indices rather than the array itself.

There's a partial_sort algorithm built into the standard library of C++, but not Fortran. Maybe you could check out how that is implemented.

```
module sorting
   implicit none

contains

   subroutine swap( a, b )
      integer, intent(inout) :: a, b
      integer temp

      temp = a
      a = b
      b = temp

   end subroutine swap

   function best_n( A, nfirst ) result( indices )
      integer, intent(in) :: A(:)
      integer, intent(in) :: nfirst
      integer, allocatable :: indices(:)
      integer n
      integer i, j, jmin
      
      n = size( A )
      indices = [ ( i, i = 1, n ) ]

      do i = 1, nfirst
         jmin = i
         do j = i + 1, n
            if ( A(indices(j)) > A(indices(jmin)) ) jmin = j
         end do
         if ( jmin /= i ) call swap( indices(i), indices(jmin) )
      end do
   
   end function best_n
   
end module sorting

!======================================================================
   
program main
   use sorting
   implicit none
   integer, allocatable :: A(:), indices(:)
   integer n
   character(len=*), parameter :: fmt = "( a, *(i3,1x) )"

   A = [ 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3 ]
   n = 3
   indices = best_n( A, n )

   write( *, fmt ) "Original array: ", A
   write( *, fmt ) "Best indices: ", indices(1:n)
   write( *, fmt ) "Best values: ", A(indices(1:n))

end program main
```

Original array:   1  -1   2  -2   3  -3
Best indices:   5   3   1
Best values:   3   2   1